# Different results of two (synonymous) queries in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have identified that some queries happen to return less results than expected. I have taken one of the missing results and tried to force Neo4j to return this result - and I succeeded with the following query:

```
match (q0),(q1),(q2),(q3),(q4),(q5)
where
  q0.name='v4' and q1.name='v3' and q2.name='v5' and
  q3.name='v1' and q4.name='v3' and q5.name='v0' and

  (q1)-->(q0) and (q0)-->(q3) and (q2)-->(q0) and (q4)-->(q0) and
  (q5)-->(q4)
return *
```

I have supposed that the following query is semantically equivalent to the previous one. However in this case, Neo4j returns no result at all.

```
match (q1)-->(q0), (q0)-->(q3), (q2)-->(q0), (q4)-->(q0), (q5)-->(q4)
where
  q0.name='v4' and q1.name='v3' and q2.name='v5' and
  q3.name='v1' and q4.name='v3' and q5.name='v0'
return *
```

I have also manually verified that the required edges among vertices `v0`, `v1`, `v3`, `v4` and `v5` are present in the database with right directions.

Am I missing some important difference between these queries or is it just a bug of Neo4j? (I have tested these queries on Neo4j 2.1.6 Community Edition.)

Thank you for any advice

/EDIT: Updating to newest version 2.2.1 was of no help.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be a complete answer, but here's what I found out.

These queries aren't synonymous, if I understand correctly.
First of all, use `EXPLAIN` (or even `PROFILE`) to look under the hood. The first query will be executed as follows:
[image]

The second query:

[image]

As you can see (even without going deep down), those are different queries in terms of both efficiency and semantics.

Next, what's actually going on here:

- the 1st query will look through all (single) nodes, filter them by name, then - try to group them according to your pattern, which will involve computing Cartesian product (hence the enormous space complexity), then collect those groups into the larger ones, and then evaluate your other conditions.
- the 2nd query will first pick a pair of nodes connected with some relationship (which satisfy the condition on the `name` property), then throw in the third node and filter again, ..., and so on till the end. The number of nodes is expected to decrease after every filter cycle.

By the way, is it possible that you accidentally set the same name twice (for `q1` and `q3`?)

Comment: Thank you! Vertices `q1` and `q4` were assigned to the vertex with the same name intentionally - I have verified that the edges (using the names) `v0-->v4`, `v3-->v4` and `v4-->v3` are all present in the database so I thought this assignment should be OK. I understand that these queries are evaluated in different ways (and I expected that the second one will be much more convenient for the optimizer to optimize). But what in the original Cypher queries makes the database to return different results? I thought that the performance of these queries may differ, but the result should be the same.

Comment: @KarelHorak, yeah, I was sure this is a feature, but now that I think of it more, I can't find a point where they begin to differ semantically. Let's wait for some 'neo4j guys' to clarify.